# Dark futuristic sci fi shorts shown on UK TV in the 90s

Tags: story-identification, tv

I distinctly remember as a kid in probably the mid-90s watching a series of one-off sci fi shorts. Quite dark / hard sci fi. Kind of a manga vibe but not necessarily Japanese. I seem to recall they (or at least this one) had little / no dialogue? Almost certainly Channel 4 / BBC2.

I remember one in particular about someone (maybe an assassin?) who had to keep shooting a crane so it wouldn't dock with her escape pod while she was trying to finish something against the clock. I'm pretty sure she died in the end.

Comment: She dies in the end of more or less each episode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be *Æon Flux*. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux) it was shown on BBC's *Liquid Television*.

> In the mid-1990s, the BBC showed the *Liquid Television* shorts, which included all of the *Æon Flux* shorts.

This is one of the characters from it which might match the style you remember.

[image: Æon Flux female character wielding a pistol]

Comment: I think that might be it! Fast work! It's taken years to work that out Many thanks.